# Prevent Linux from sleeping when Python process running

Tags: python, linux, process, sleep-mode

**Is there a (programmatic) way to prevent my Linux (Ubuntu) from going into sleep mode while my Python program is running?** I seek a solution that avoids me manually changing the OS power settings each time I run my code.

Background: I'm running a long machine learning training from within PyCharm (using Ray RLlib). While I would have hoped for the intense active process to prevent the sleeping, my Ubuntu falls asleep after my standard power settings' suspension period is up if I don't interact during the training.

I am surprised to not find any solution when googling and looking at Stackoverflow; it would seem such a common need for Python (or maybe other) programmers, and I would have expected some python tools to exist to readily allow to prevent the sleeping from within my Python script itself.

I found [SetThreadExecutionState](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34836464/3673329) for Windows (with C++), but nothing so far for Linux. A slightly less focused question [Prevent sleep mode python (Wakelock on python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57647034/prevent-sleep-mode-python-wakelock-on-python) is also related to my issue, but it has not attracted any answer solving the case for the Linux OS.

Comment: Try `systemd-inhibit <your command>`!

Comment: If you can do it "manually" you can do it automatically. Let your script set up power to prevent sleeping at its start and resume default values at its end.

Comment: Not directly. The problem is that there are tons of applications that work in background like for example a screen saver, so the inactivity timer only considers input interactions. I know no direct Python interface for that, you you will have to find a command that changes the timer behaviour and runs it through subprocess from your code.

Comment: @tansy Thanks, correct. My script tends to crash, I tend to run sub-parts, etc.; so in worst case I should use that strategy but nicer would be a less 'system-settings-intrusive' way.

Comment: Thanks Serge Ballesta. That makes complete sense, I thought sth like that might be the case. Maybe the least intrusive albeit slightly involved way could be to create a small python facility emulating a mouse movement by + & - 1 px, say, if no input seems to have happened for the past 10min or so. I guess that is possible in a 'genuine' enough way such as for the OS to count it as user input. I might check out whether I can readily implement that and post it as answer if none else proposes sth ready-made (or tells me why I might be on the wrong track here).

Answer (score 3):

You can try [Deluge-PreventSuspendPlus](https://github.com/h3llrais3r/Deluge-PreventSuspendPlus), version of [Deluge-PreventSuspend-plugin](https://github.com/ianmartin/Deluge-PreventSuspend-plugin). It is in python, uses DBus and Gnome Session Manager, but you can adapt it as well.

There are "inhibitor" classes in `core.py` where you will find how exactly it works.

Answer (score -1):

sudo systemctl mask sleep.target

sudo systemctl mask suspend.target

sudo systemctl mask hibernate.target

sudo systemctl mask hybrid-sleep.target

see the web page: https://linux-tips.us/how-to-disable-sleep-and-hibernation-on-ubuntu-server/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Seems like this solution will make your machine never sleep, rather than only during the running of your program.